# panic: assignment to entry in nil map on single simple map

Tags: dictionary, go

I was under the impression that the assignment to entry in nil map error would only happen if we would want to assign to a double map, that is, when a map on a deeper level is trying to be assigned while the higher one doesn't exist, e.g.:

```
var mm map[int]map[int]int
mm[1][2] = 3
```

But it also happens for a simple map (though with struct as a key):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type COO struct {
    x int
    y int
}

var neighbours map[COO][]COO

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 20; j++ {
            var buds []COO
            if i < 29 {
                buds = append(buds, COO{x: i + 1, y: j})
            }
            if i > 0 {
                buds = append(buds, COO{x: i - 1, y: j})
            }
            if j < 19 {
                buds = append(buds, COO{x: i, y: j + 1})
            }
            if j > 0 {
                buds = append(buds, COO{x: i, y: j - 1})
            }
            neighbours[COO{x: i, y: j}] = buds // <--- yields error
        }
    }


    fmt.Println(neighbours)

}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize neighbours: `var neighbours = make(map[COO][]COO)`

See the second section in: https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

You'll get a panic whenever you try to insert a value into a map that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: So we actually have to write the definition twice? When the value changes, it has to be changed at 2 places. Seems very weird. At least it worked.

Comment: So currently your code declares that `neighbours` will exist, but it doesn't actually ask for memory for it. We have to ask for memory for it before we can put any data in it. So it's not so much writing the definition twice, as making sure we get memory for the map.

Comment: Oh it can, that's why I wrote `var neighbours = make(map[COO][]COO)`, you can put that instead of `var neighbours map[COO][]COO`. The confusion stems probably from the fact that a nil slice is valid to use for normal slice operations, but a nil map isn't valid to use for map operations.

Comment: Could have sworn it gave an error message when I tried it, but copying from you did the trick! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In Golang, everything is initialized to a `zero value`, it's the default value for uninitialized variables.

So, as it has been conceived, a map's zero value is nil. When trying to use an non-initialized map, it panics. (Kind of a null pointer exception)

Sometimes it can be useful, because if you know the zero value of something you don't have to initialize it explicitly:

```
var str string
str += "42"
fmt.Println(str)
// 42 ; A string zero value is ""

var i int
i++
fmt.Println(i)
// 1 ; An int zero value is 0

var b bool
b = !b
fmt.Println(b)
// true ; A bool zero value is false
```

If you have a Java background, that's the same thing: primitive types have a default value and objects are initialized to null;

Now, for more complex types like `chan` and `map`, the zero value is `nil`, that's why you have to use `make` to instantiate them. Pointers also have a nil zero value. The case of arrays and slice is a bit more tricky:

```
var a [2]int
fmt.Println(a)
// [0 0]

var b []int
fmt.Println(b)
// [] ; initialized to an empty slice
```

The compiler knows the length of the array (it cannot be changed) and its type, so it can already instantiate the right amount of memory. All of the values are initialized to their zero value (unlike C where you can have anything inside your array). For the slice, it is initialized to the empty slice `[]`, so you can use `append` normally.

Now, for structs, it is the same as for arrays. Go creates a struct with all its fields initialized to zero values. It makes a deep initialization, example here:

```
type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

type Line struct {
    a Point
    b Point
}

func main() {
    var line Line
    // the %#v format prints Golang's deep representation of a value
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", line)
}
// main.Line{a:main.Point{x:0, y:0}, b:main.Point{x:0, y:0}}
```

Finally, the `interface` and `func` types are also initialized to nil.

That's really all there is to it. When working with complex types, you just have to remember to initialize them. The only exception is for arrays because you can't do `make([2]int)`.

In your case, you have map of slice, so you need at least two steps to put something inside: Initialize the nested slice, and initialize the first map:

```
var buds []COO
neighbours := make(map[COO][]COO)
neighbours[COO{}] = buds

// alternative (shorter)
neighbours := make(map[COO][]COO)

// You have to use equal here because the type of neighbours[0] is known
neighbours[COO{}] = make([]COO, 0)
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you've written, but you don't have to initialize a slice in order to append to it (a nil slice is valid to append to).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for correcting me ! I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: np! I'm just lazy and love using nil slices to start if I don't know what capacity I'll actually need lol.